# Reshaping with asterisk operator `*` in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

While reading [this](https://huggingface.co/blog/annotated-diffusion) annotated implementation of *Diffusion Probabilistic models* in PyTorch, I got stuck at understanding this function

```
def extract(a, t, x_shape):
    batch_size = t.shape[0]
    out = a.gather(-1, t.cpu())
    return out.reshape(batch_size, *((1,) * (len(x_shape) - 1))).to(t.device)
```

What it's not clear it's the final return statement, what does the `*((1,)` mean into `reshape` function? Does that asterisk correspond to the unpacking operator? And if yes, how is it used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
(1,) * (len(x_shape) - 1))
```

means to create a tuple with length `len(x_shape) - 1` filled with just `1`s

```py
*(...)
```

means to spread the tuple into arguments

So it ends up being (say `len(x_shape)` == 5)

```py
return out.reshape(batch_size, 1, 1, 1, 1).to(t.device)
```